# Android UI Crash due to kernel error

Tags: android

When I return error from linux system calls like `create`/`open` etc. in order to fail such operations from my App, complete Android UI crashes. When I investigated more I realized that root cause is the system_server crashing because of my errors from system call.

I tried using errors like EACCESS, EBADF etc but each of these seems to be considered as a fatal exception by Android!

Any idea on non-fatal error values which I can use such that it does not cause Android UI to crash?